# Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Window(...).Window'

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have been getting this run-time error frequently while developing automated tests with UFT 12.53.

```
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Window(...).Window'

Line (9): "Window("regexpwndtitle:=Nextech \(MU_MASTER\)").Window("regexpwndtitle:=Patients").WinButton("regexpwndtitle:=New").Click".
```

I can provide more details if need be.  Windows 10 OS.  Tried to research Similar Questions to no avail.  Thanks!

Comment: I would like to understand, what line of code appears in the test when you try to record the same step using record button.

Comment: `Window("Nextech (MU_MASTER)").Window("Patients").WinButton("New").Click`

Comment: So it records objects and puts them into the OR.  The Window...Window object seems to be fine for something in the OR.  Trying to avoid using an OR.

Comment: Yes agree, I was just trying to check the hierarchy that UFT produces. I copied your above statement and ran in my UFT multiple times, it doesn't throw the error you have mentioned. It throws that cannot find object ... which is as expected

Comment: Post a snapshot of your OR here..

Comment: And please check the identification and native(if available) properties when you get the error for any clues.

Comment: Hello Kira. How to paste.  Isn't working

Comment: Mithilesh, you had the solution.  It was a duplicate name in the OR that was causing the problem!

Answer (score 0):

May be WinButton will comes on Dialog box right You can try below code once

```
Window("regexpwndtitle:=Nextech \(MU_MASTER\)").Dialog("regexpwndtitle:=Patients").WinButton("regexpwndtitle:=New").Click".
```

May Be this will works.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the second window to dialog did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Window("text:=WinSCP").Window("text:=Login").WinObject("nativeclass:=TButton","text:=    Login").highlight
```

for which I was getting that 
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Window(...).Window'

I removed the object repository related to the the first Window and it worked for me.